# Get information about about the role that creates an AWS resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam, roles

Im creating a lambda function to tag resources with a specific tag depending on the **role** that creates the resource:

```
if role = dev:  
then 
ec2.create_tags(Resources=instance_ids,Tags=[{'Key':'environnement','Value':'dev'}]) 
elif role = prod: 
ec2.create_tags(Resources=instance_ids,Tags=[{'Key':'environnement','Value':'prod'}])

.....
```

My question:
How can I get information about the role that creates the resource?

**Thanks in advance !!**

Comment: I do not think you can get the principal or role that created the ec2 instance from the [DescribeInstances API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeInstances.html). Why don't you tag the instance upon creation instead?

Comment: I agree with the comment above, you cannot get this info from DescribeInstances. A different approach would be to trigger this lambda based on certain CloudWatch events (like when the instance is started/created) and then using the InstanceId look up the corresponding event in CloudTrail to see which role performed the action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS resources do not store "who" created the resource.

When an API call is sent to AWS to create a resource, AWS will check whether the provided credentials are permitted to create the resource (eg an Amazon EC2 instance). If they are permitted, then the resource is created and the resource is **associated with an AWS account**. No indication of *who* made the API request is stored on the resource.

However, you can use **AWS CloudTrail** to view an audit log of API calls, including the identity that made the API call. This identity might be associated with an IAM User or an IAM Role, or even the root credentials of the AWS account.

From [Using AWS Lambda with Amazon CloudWatch Events - AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-cloudwatchevents.html):

> Amazon CloudWatch events help you to respond to state changes in your AWS resources. When your resources change state, they automatically send events into an event stream. You can create rules that match selected events in the stream and route them to your AWS Lambda function to take action.

Thus, you can configure CloudWatch Events to trigger the Lambda function whenever a specific event happens (eg `RunInstances`). Full details of the event will be passed to the Lambda function, so it can determine *who* triggered that event.

Comment: Hello thanks for your response.
I have verified that using cloudTrail, I can see who created the resource, but how can I use this information from the lambda function?

Comment: What is currently triggering your Lambda function? You could trigger it from Amazon CloudWatch Events whenever a relevant action occurs in CloudTrail, such as `RunInstances`. I've updated my answer.